# Error changing datetime format from python to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am using Python to load my data into SQL Server. I would like to change the format of `ScheduledStartDate` from "20-APR-2021 09:00:00 AM" to "2021-04-20 09:00:00"

```
df['ScheduledStartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ScheduledStartDate'])
df['ScheduledStartDate'] = df['ScheduledStartDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, I get this error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: In SQL server, datatype is not a datetime. How do you query for the data? you might have to use: CAST and CONVERT to change the datatype before you get it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server `datetime` is a [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the type of your ScheduledStartDate column. Internally the date you insert in that table is not really formatted, you can read the first failure of this [post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/) about this common mistake. But when you do a SELECT and get the date formated as `20-APR-2021 09:00:00 AM` it is not because it is stored that way, it is just being shown in that format as default and matching your Operating System date format preferences.

This being said, you should store the dates from python without formatting it and then format the datetime column when it is being retrieved. Like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,ScheduledStartDate,20), *
FROM table
```

Where `20` is the `Date Format Code` for `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`